# Trigger UILocalNotification from WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an Xcode project in Swift with the following targets:

- iOS App
- WatchKit Extension / WatchKit App
- "Common" Project, used by the "main" project and by the extension

In the common project I have the following code:

```
public class func scheduleNotification(seconds: Int) {
  var notification = UILocalNotification()
  notification.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(seconds))

  notification.alertBody = "item"
  notification.alertAction = "open"
  notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
  notification.userInfo = ["UUID": "XX", ]
  notification.category = "CATEGORY"
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

I'm able to call this method AND fire a notification from the iOS APP:

```
@IBAction func XXX(sender: AnyObject) {
  NotificationHelper.scheduleNotification(100)
}
```

But the same code executed from the WatchKit Extension doesn't fire any notification. The method IS called but then nothing happens on the iPhone or on the Apple Watch, no notifications are fired.

Can someone help me?

How can I schedule notification from the WatchKit Extension logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App extensions are not allowed to access `sharedApplication`. I'm guessing that `sharedApplication` is returning `nil` in your case, which would explain why the notification is not scheduled.

I'd suggest using something like `openParentApplication:reply:` to open your host iOS app in the background and schedule the notification from there.

Comment: Thanks, super quick answer! ;)

Comment: But how do you get a local notification to show up on the watch, because I want it to display just in case the phone isn't near by. so what modifications would I have to make to Guido's code for it work that way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you do NOT yet have the real device, but are using the simulator? Then you will probably not be able to send notifications to the Watch at all. This is because Apple has not (yet) added this feature to XCode.

To view and test your notification interface on the watch simulator, use a payload file as described here (paragraph "Specifying a Notification Payload for Testing"):
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html

And do not have much confidence in a change of that coming soon/anymore. As it is described somewhere in the Watch Documentation, iOS will decide itself where to send your notification, anyway (when you finally made it to the hardware release...)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I own the real device and I was able to schedule notifications by using openParentApplication:reply: as suggested by @bgilham

Comment: Oh okay, that is interesting! I seem to be a little out of date since I am still waiting for my watch.. But were you able to explicitly fire notifications TO the watch, too?

Comment: I quote from the Apple Watch App: _Notification alerts appear on Apple Watch when you're wearing it and it's unlocked. And you don't get alerts on your Apple Watch if you're actively using your iPhone._

So basically you are able to schedule a notification and then, depending if you are using the phone or not, it will appear on the phone OR on the watch.

Comment: Okay, that was what I had in mind. I see I intitially misread your question a little, I thought you were trying to schedule notifications on the watch, not from the watch. Sorry for that

Comment: FYI...to test notifications on the Watch hardware, turn off Wrist Detection in the General settings of the Apple Watch Companion app.

Answer (score -1):

First of all run `iOS` app from `WatchKit` app:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"text":@"Hello world!",
                           @"delay":@10.0};
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:userInfo reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
    // Completion
}];
```

Then handle on `iOS` device:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier tid = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];

    UILocalNotification *note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    note.alertBody = userInfo[@"text"];
    note.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[userInfo[@"delay"] doubleValue]];
    note.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    note.userInfo = userInfo;
    [application scheduleLocalNotification:note];

    reply(nil); // Completion callback
    [application endBackgroundTask:tid];
}
```

And of course do not forget to register `iOS` app for notifications:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil]];
    return YES;
}
```